# Why won't Nginx return a 404 error for URLs starting with a question mark?

Tags: nginx, https, 301-redirect

I'm trying to get a rewrite rule working and I've discovered that if the URL begins with a question mark, Nginx fails to return 404 error as expected. Instead, index.html as defined in the root directive is served for all urls beginning with "?". (e.g. `example.com/?page-does-not-exist` works for the home page but should not)

This is making it impossible to get a redirect from `example.com/?format=feed&amp;type=rss` -> `example.com/rss.xml` working. This is for a blog migrated from Joomla to Jekyll.

Put simply, visiting **example.com/123 returns a 404**, and visiting **example.com/?123 does not**. The latter returns the site's home page at the URL example.com?/123. (There is no file or folder '123', so requests for it should always fail.)

Everything works perfectly with the site, including the HTTPS redirect, except for the expected 404 redirects not happening for URLs starting with a question mark. How do I fix this?

Here's my configuration:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html;
    listen 443;
    ssl on;      
    ...

    rewrite "/?format=feed&amp;type=rss" https://example.com/rss.xml permanent;

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|txt|svg|eot|woff|ttf)$ {
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            valid_referers none blocked example.com;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
                    return 403;
            }
    }
}

# HTTP --> HTTPS
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question mark signifies the end of the path portion of the uri and the beginning of the query string. Hence why nginx will not return 404 based on the portion after the question mark; the requested resource does exist and the query string parameters are just passed to it.

Regarding the other part of the question, I believe that nginx's rewrite statement does not actually match against the query string portion of the uri.

You should however be able to do something along the lines of:

```
if ($args ~ "format=feed&type=rss") {
    rewrite ^ https://example.com/rss.xml? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Nginx's docs say ['if is evil'](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and recommend against using it, plus this unfortunately didn't work when I just tested it. I still get the home page for `example.com/?format=feed&amp;type=rss` instead of a redirect or 404.

Comment: Do you actually have `&amp;` in your query strings? I assumed that was a mistake in the question and you really meant `&`? (HTML encoding things in the query string seems like really weird practice.)

Comment: I have subscribers requesting both types subscribed to the RSS feed, so ultimately I'd like both to work. I'm getting hits for `/?format=feed&amp;type=rss` and `/?format=feed&type=rss`.

Comment: Ok, and my suggestion does not work for the `/?format=feed&type=rss` case? (Which seems like the sane case.)

Comment: No, didn't work and I'm sure I copied it exactly. it returns `example.com/rss.xml?format=feed&type=rss` with a "The page isn't redirecting properly" error. Tested with it in the main server block + in a location / {...} block, same thing. (plus obviously reloading Nginx each time.

Comment: Okay, if you end the target url in the rewrite with a question mark it should wipe the existing query string parameters.  If "example.com" is actually the same domain I suppose the original example could cause a loop, maybe that is what you experienced. If it's actually a local resource you may want to consider [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) instead.

Comment: This worked, but I adapted the args to `($args ~ "type=rss")` which when combined with your first edit to the redirect target URL works perfectly for both variants. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

`NGinx` interprets everything that follows a `?` as a query string, not as a path.

It will only return a 404 for a non-existing path, not for a query string.

eg :

- `example.com/123` : if path `/123` exists and if there is an index file for this path then it's OK, else it will return a 404
- `example.com/?123` : if there is an index file in the root directory
  for `example.com` then it's OK. It does not check if directory `?123` exists as it does not consider this as a path but as a query string.

Comment: So is it possible to either redirect or rewrite requests for `example.com/?123` to something else. or is this impossible with Nginx? (I can ask this as a new question if that's best)

Comment: You are right to ask it here, i think it's possible, will have look at it right now. But there is something that confuse me : you do a rewrite for `/?format=feed&amp;type=rss`, so i am not sure which exact case you want to handle.

Comment: Joomla's default RSS feed for the old site was `example.com/?format=feed&type=rss` which some feed readers (I'm guessing?) replace with `example.com/?format=feed&amp;type=rss` as the second type has 3x the hits in my logs. I want both to redirect or rewrite to `example.com/rss.xml` permanently

Comment: So the previous answer provides the solution. IfIsEvil, for sure, but have a look at the first sample on the IfIsEvil page : `There are cases where you simply cannot avoid using an if`